# How wp_posts and wp_postmeta are connected in mysql?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How are WordPress `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` connected in MySQL? Thank you in advance..

Comment: check   https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: I need the foreign key to connect those table which is foreign key i dont get that..

Comment: did you checked wp_posts table and wp_postmeta table ?

Comment: Yes i checked but no solution found

Answer (score 2):

The `post_id` is an index in the `wp_postmeta` table.

More info [in the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/974ca19e36dd71e7c506de05ca862d29a134e6dc/wp-admin/includes/schema.php#L144).

Comment: I need the foreign key to connect those table which is foreign key i dont get that..

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Based on the link mentioned above, I was able to create this pattern to search custom posts_types based on 3 meta_values and 1 custom taxonomy.

So my structure is:   Each custom post (talents) has 3 custom fields (City, Country, Gender).
    Each custom post belongs to the custom taxonomy "Languages" with certain categories such as English, Spanish, Russian etc.

So the query bellow is looking for a female in Canada, Toronto who can speak French.

```
 <?php
    global $wpdb; // define global keyword

    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta v1 ON (wp_posts.ID = v1.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta v2 ON (wp_posts.ID = v2.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta v3 ON (wp_posts.ID = v3.post_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id) 
    WHERE
    wp_terms.name = 'French' AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'Languages' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'talents' 
    AND v1.meta_value = 'Toronto'
    AND v2.meta_value = 'Canada'
    AND v3.meta_value = 'female' 
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC"; // Make query

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query); //if Pass the variable in get_results function than get results

    print_r($result);

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you but i got empty table while running this code.

Comment: define `global $wpdb` and try this